# Unified input for button

Tags: wpf, input

I'm new to WPF and I was just trying to run some code when a button is pressed (using any type of input device).

However when I looked at the Button events I saw quite a few that would match:

- MouseDown
- KeyDown
- StylusDown
- TouchDown
- PreviewMouseDown
- PreviewKeyDown
- PreviewStylusDown
- PreviewTouchDown

I don't think Click is suitable for me since I need to know when the button is released.
So, do I have to write an event handler for each of these events or is there a simple way of including all input types?

Also what's the difference between the "Preview" events and the regular ones (couldn't find it on MSDN)?

Comment: The `Preview` events occur before the actual event occur, so `PreviewMouseDown` occurs right before the `MouseDown` event. I'm not sure if there's an easy way to set the handler for all input devices at once, but you should only need to set the first 4 or the last 4 of the ones you have listed - if you set both the regular events and the `Preview` events the code will get run twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that you do want the Click event.

Note that the WPF Button has a ClickMode property that controls when the Click event is raised.

[ButtonBase.ClickMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.clickmode.aspx)

The default value for the ClickMode property is Release which `Specifies that the Click event should be raised when a button is pressed and released.`

[ClickMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.clickmode.aspx)

Like Rachel said, the preview events occur before the actual events occur.

The Click event won't work because you want events both when the button is pressed and released. You might be able to bind to the [IsPressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.ispressed.aspx) property.

```
<Style x:Key="Triggers" TargetType="Button">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
      <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you need events to be raised, you might be able use an [EventSetter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter.aspx), instead of a Setter in the trigger.

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to achieve. I want to play a sound only while the button is pressed. That means I need both a "ButtonDown" event to start playing the sound, and a "ButtonUp" event to pause the sound. The Click event would work if I could set ClickMode to be both "Release" and "Press" and figure out in the event handler if the button is pressed or not. But I don't think that is possible :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use one event handler for all events, would that help?

```
   <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,84,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" 
                        MouseDown="button1_generalInput"
                        KeyDown="button1_generalInput"
                        StylusDown="button1_generalInput"
                        TouchDown="button1_generalInput"/>

private void button1_generalInput(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: I've thought of that as well, but I was hoping there's an easier way. It seems like so much work for such a simple task.